Navbar hamburger being cut off on the bottom of hamburger
I am trying to implement a hamburger menu in a React + Tailwind component, but the bottom layer of the hamburger menu is being cut off half way through, so the bottom line is not completely full. I do not understand why. I am attaching a screenshot of the problem.
I am also including the image below.

import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="bg-gradient-to-r from-red-600 to-orange-500 p-4">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-between items-center">
        <a href="/" className="flex items-center">
          <img
            src="/pizza-logo.png"
            alt="Paolo's Pizza Logo"
            className="h-12 w-12 rounded-full border-2 border-white"
          />
          <span className="hidden sm:block text-white text-2xl font-semibold ml-4">
            Paolo's Pizza and Ristorante
          </span>
        </a>

        <div className="sm:hidden">
          <button
            onClick={toggleMenu}
            className="text-white focus:outline-none"
          >
            <svg
              className="w-8 h-8"
              fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                strokeWidth="2"
                d="M4 6h16M4 12h16m-7 6h7"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>

        <ul className="hidden sm:flex space-x-8 text-lg text-white font-rubik">
          <li>
            <a href="#home" className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#menu" className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded">
              Menu
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#reservations"
              className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded"
            >
              Reservations
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about" className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded">
              About Us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#contact"
              className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded"
            >
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      {isOpen && (
        <div className="sm:hidden mt-4">
          <ul className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 text-white">
            <li>
              <a
                href="#home"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#menu"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Menu
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#reservations"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Reservations
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#about"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                About Us
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#contact"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

I was expecting the hamburger menu to appear as normal, and I have tried adjusting various Tailwind utility classes, but I couldn't get it to work.
Here is the image of the hamburger part of the navbar not appearing

I think the screenshot is missing?

It seems like the d command in the <path> element for the SVG would not draw what you intend:
Start at 0,0
     0
       ↘
         ↘
           1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2 h16
         M4 6                         ↙   Draw horizontally 16 units
      Move to 4,6             ← ← ← ←
             ↙ ← ← ← ← ← ← ↙
           3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4 h16
         M4 12                        ↙   Draw horizontally 16 units
      Move to 4,12                ← ←
                          ↙ ← ← ↙
                        5 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6 h7
                      m-7 6               Draw horizontally 7 units
        Move left 7 units and move down 6 units

The last command only moves the "pointer" back 7 units, whereas the other commands move back to 4 on the x-axis. Thus, the last line starts from 13 instead of 4 (like the other lines).
You could consider reworking the last 2 commands to be the same as the other commands, to draw the line fully:
Start at 0,0
     0
       ↘
         ↘
           1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2 h16
         M4 6                         ↙   Draw horizontally 16 units
      Move to 4,6             ← ← ← ←
             ↙ ← ← ← ← ← ← ↙
           3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4 h16
         M4 12                        ↙   Draw horizontally 16 units
      Move to 4,12           　← ← ← ←
             ↙ ← ← ← ← ← ← ↙
           5 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6 h16
         M4 18                            Draw horizontally 16 units
      Move to 4,18



const { useState } = React;

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="bg-gradient-to-r from-red-600 to-orange-500 p-4">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-between items-center">
        <a href="/" className="flex items-center">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/48/48"
            alt="Paolo's Pizza Logo"
            className="h-12 w-12 rounded-full border-2 border-white"
          />
          <span className="hidden sm:block text-white text-2xl font-semibold ml-4">
            Paolo's Pizza and Ristorante
          </span>
        </a>

        <div className="sm:hidden">
          <button
            onClick={toggleMenu}
            className="text-white focus:outline-none"
          >
            <svg
              className="w-8 h-8"
              fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                strokeWidth="2"
                d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>

        <ul className="hidden sm:flex space-x-8 text-lg text-white font-rubik">
          <li>
            <a href="#home" className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#menu" className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded">
              Menu
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#reservations"
              className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded"
            >
              Reservations
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about" className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded">
              About Us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#contact"
              className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-2 py-1 rounded"
            >
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      {isOpen && (
        <div className="sm:hidden mt-4">
          <ul className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 text-white">
            <li>
              <a
                href="#home"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#menu"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Menu
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#reservations"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Reservations
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#about"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                About Us
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#contact"
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="hover:bg-orange-700 px-4 py-2 rounded"
              >
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </nav>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Navbar/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



